# Exporting lots of .doc files with mathtype equations and vector drawings to html with embedded latex and svg

Tags: ms-word, wmf, mathtype

I need to convert thousands of .doc files to HTML. These documents contain MathType equations, Word Drawings (vector drawings), and the drawings many times contain more equation objects themselves.
Through Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word I have managed to save .docs to filtered HTML and "unfiltered" HTML (this last mode has the advantage of generating several .wmz files). Sadly, the MathType SDK fails to convert every single equation in the wmz files that are generated in the process (the wmf examples that come with the SDK are converted to LaTeX just fine..).  **Summing up:**

- I need to know which wmf files are MathType equations and which are word drawings;
- I need to be able to convert the wmf files that are MathType equations to LaTeX.
- I need some PRETTY good wmf to svg converters to convert the drawings, because it is quite often that the results are not to our liking;
- I need to have access to the mathtype equations contained in the word drawings.

All of this has to be automated, since there are thousands of files.
Anyone with some experience on this?

Comment: I did this a while ago, though not with maths equations and there were a couple of ways to walk the word document object tree. Have you tried manually reading the Word drawing object and then outputting each equation object in there?  If you can find an example where that fails, then it may be a bug that Microsoft may already have a patch for.

Comment: @acutesoftware I'm almost settling with "losing" the equations inside the drawings (this means being ok with just the vector information generated for them in either wmf or emf formats). The problem still lies in converting equations to LaTeX with the MathType SDK and wmf/emf to SVG. Also, to access the objects I'm currently saving the document as .docx and looking at the .bin files inside it, though I could easily change this if it is worth it.

Comment: It would be easier to to this in .NET and use the object model MS provides rather than read the .bin  files - this way MS can solve the problem for you. You are dealing with a proprietary format, and any solution you do now may break in the next release.

Comment: @acutesoftware your concern is valid, but this is a one time importing process, so it is not a big worry. Either way, I'll settle with whatever is easier.

Answer (score 0):

WMZ is gzipped WMF, so if the conversion of WMF to LaTeX works, then try unGzipping the WMZ file to WMF and then converting it to LaTeX.

Comment: Actually, wmz is zipped wmf. wmz files aren`t the problem, the problem (among others) is converting wmf to LaTeX.